# Which of the following group has a proper subgroup that is not cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Which of the following group has a proper subgroup that is not cyclic?

$1$. $\mathbb Z_{15} \times \mathbb Z_{17}$.

$2$. $S_3$

$3$. ($\mathbb Z$,+)

$4$. ($\mathbb Q$,+)

- the proper subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{15} \times \mathbb Z_{17}$ have possible orders $3,5,15,17,51,85$ & all groups of orders $3,5,15,17,51,85$ are cyclic.So,all proper subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{15} \times \mathbb Z_{17}$  are cyclic.
- Every proper subgroup of $S_3$ is cyclic.So,it is not the answer.
- ($\mathbb Z$,+) is a cyclic group generated by $1$.And every proper subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.So,it is not the answer.
- Any finitely generated subgroup of ($\mathbb Q$,+) is cyclic.So,it is not the answer.

The answer given in the answer key is $4$.

Please help me knowing which point i'm missing.

Comment: Why did you restrict yourself to finitely generated subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @carmichael561:because i think any finitely generated subgroup will also be the subgroup.Is there difference between finitely generated subgroup  and ordinary subgroups of a group?

Comment: Yes, because there could be subgroups which aren't finitely generated.

Comment: @carmichael561:Will you please specify with the help of an example?

Comment: Robert Z's answer is a nice example.

Comment: @carmichael561:Yeah i got it.thank you

Comment: By the way, your argument for #1 isn't valid. The opposite of "has a proper subgroup that isn't cyclic" is "all proper subgroups are cyclic", You've only shown that it has at least one cyclic proper subgroup.

Comment: @user275313:My bad,the proper subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{15} \times \mathbb Z_{17}$ have possible orders $3,5,15,17,51,85$ & all groups of orders $3,5,15,17,51,85$ are cyclic.So,all proper subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{15} \times \mathbb Z_{17}$  are cyclic.

Comment: @user275313:thanks a lot for pointing this.

Comment: No problem. (You've actually left me wondering what the precise condition is for a finite Abelian group to have all of its subgroups be cyclic, but you don't need that for your particular problem.)

Comment: @user275313:good,i did'nt get that thought.So,have you reached to some conclusion?

Comment: I came up with some ideas, but then I noticed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761823/a-finite-abelian-group-that-does-not-contain-a-subgroup-isomorphic-to-mathbb-z?rq=1) in the "Related" column on the right which seems to contain the core of my solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. As regards 4. what about $\left\{\frac{m}{2^n} : m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$.